# Why am I missing an input in a form after scaffolding in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Rails and I try to use scaffold to generate some code.

Everything seems to be OK after this except I miss an input in one of my forms and I don't know why.

Someone could explain this ?

[image: Screenshot]

Here the partial form which generates the view:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: advertisement, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if advertisement.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(advertisement.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this advertisement from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% advertisement.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :price %>
    <%= form.number_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :state %>
    <%= form.text_field :state %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The HTML output for this input:

```
 <div class="field">
    <label for="advertisement_title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="advertisement[title]" id="advertisement_title" />
 </div>
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: could be a CSS problem. Can you post also the HTML output of your view?
<br/> "Right-click on chrome, select 'Inspect', then copy the HTML-code of the form."

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it!

It's because of the Adblock extension.
On every page where it is enabled, it injects CSS directly into the page and adds a

```
display: none !important;
```

for hundreds of defined id's.

Unfortunately for me, #advertisement_title is one of them!

It works when I desactivate it

[adblock display none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMo9N.png)

Comment: Good job tracking it down. Would have never guessed that we the culprit. You can override the id with `<%= form.text_field :title, id: 'some_other_id' %>`. The ID does not really matter unless you're using the selector in your CSS or JS.